# Git - how to setup branching in a dev team?

Tags: git, github

I want to use git in my dev department since we are working with multiple developers on different locations on 1 application.

We were thinking about using SourceTree as Git client. Github as repo host.

I understand the concepts of workflow. But I wonder how to use it within a team.

In the default setup you work with a master and a develop branch. Should I continue with that when we develop in a team? Alternative I was thinking each developer could define his own develop branch e.g.labeled Nick , Steve, Amanda and merge there changes from there to the master origin.

Are there benefits to move away from the the default develop and master branch when working in a team or not? If so what are they?

If you happen to have recommendations for me to use Git, Github in a team environment?

Answer (score 4):

**Branching model**
Branching model are 6 kinds of branch :

**develop**: Develop branch contains the latest delivered development changes.

**feature/xxx**: Feature branches are dedicated branch for one big feature (lot of commits), "xxx" is the feature name.

**stable/xxx**: Stable branch are used to perform releases and write / accept fix. "xxx" is the stable version name (e.g 1.0.x).

**fix/xxx**: Fix branch is dedicated to integrate bugfix on Develop branch. If needed the fix is then cherry pick on stable branch.

**integration/xxx**: Integration branches are dedicated branch to automatic integration task (like Crowdin translation).

**poc/xxx**: Poc branches are dedicated branch to develop a Prove of Concept (PoC).

***Develop Branch***

Develop branch contains the latest delivered development changes. This is our backbone where all the different fix and new feature are mixed with each other.

[image]

***Feature Branch***
Feature branches are dedicated branch to develop a new feature.
[image]

Comment: you mean all developers work on the same develop branch?

Comment: From my hand-ons experience, In almost case, almost developers work on same develop branch. My answer merely like a suggestion.